# Short animation class in Pygame?

Tags: python, class, object, python-2.7, pygame

I litterally have no idea still as to how to use classes. I just need to do an 18 frame animation and have the capability of doing it anywhere (25 times) in a 5x5 grid. Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Anyway, this is what I have so far:

```
class showRectangles:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def flipcard(self):
    while showrect:
      pygame.draw.rect(window,black,[self.position,75*scale,75*scale])
    self.blitoptions = self.image,self.position,[[55,self.frame,0],[75*scale,75*scale]]
    window.blit(pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.blitoptions,75*scale).convert_alpha())
    if self.flipping and self.frame != 18:
      self.frame += 1
    else:
      self.flipping = False

class boardCard(showRectangles):

  def __init__(self,pos):
    self.position = pos
    self.rect = Rect(self.position[0]*scale,self.position[1]*scale,self.position[0]+75*scale,self.position[1]+75*scale)
    self.flipping = False
    self.frame = 0
    self.image = themedb["default"]["images"]["flipanimation"]


  # def getrect(self):
  #   return pygame.rect(int(self.position[0]),int(self.position[1]),int(self.position[0])+75*scale,int(self.position[1])+75*scale)
```

Variables:

Showrect shows the areas that are clickable as a sort of "debug view".

Scale is what resizes the window and images on it.

ThemeDB is the set of themes for the game. "FlipAnimation.png" is stored here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the [python tutorials](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)? They have a great explanation about classes.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems that you have a grid of rectangles, and after a click, you want to flip the card with an animation.

What you want is to define a class MyRectangle, that will have the methods `__init__`, `draw` and `update`. Here is an short example:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,pos):
        self.flipping = false
        self.images = loadImages()
        self.frame = 0
        self.pos = pos
    def flip():
        self.flipping = true
    def update():
        if self.flipping:
            self.frame += 1
            self.frame %= len(self.images)
    def draw(screen):
        screen.blit(self.images[self.frame],self.pos)
```

Your main loop code will look like this:

```
cards = []
for x in range(10):
   for y in range(10):
      cards.append(Card((x*10,y*10)))
while not finished:
    for card in cards:
        card.draw(screen)
        card.update()
#somewhere in the event loop:
    card.flip()
```

Comment: I've tried reading them, having a friend explain them, and watched several people explain them on YouTube. I know how and why they work, but for some reason I don't know how to apply them to what I'm trying to do. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Think of it as parts of something bigger. Each object has methods that are called to change its state, or respond to an action. In this case the Card could be in a Class called Board, that will have a list of Cards.

Comment: @Kweb123 Call what individually? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Each card. Each of the 25 cards needs to flip at different times, but it's currently set to flip all off them at once, isn't it?